# Is "Reminder me " correct or not?

Tags: word-choice

I want to name my Android app "Reminder me" in place of "Remind me".

I want to know whether this is a valid word or not.

Comment: What did you find in your dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Leaving aside the spelling error (I believe you mean Remi**N**der Me, not Rem**id**er Me), it's not correct English.

[Reminder](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reminder) is a noun, not a verb.

That having been said, no industry has perverted the grammar and syntax of English like the computer industry has. Nouns have been verbed (sic), verbs have been nouned (sic) and don't even ask about what has been done to those poor adverbs. There are doubtless many applications and apps that use a distorted if memorable naming syntax like that. You could claim, for example, that "Reminder Me" is an abbreviated form of "send a reminder to me", or the more hipster "hit me with a reminder".

If you want to use that as a name, I would say have at it as long as you realise that it isn't "correct" English. There have been far, far worse abominations committed in the name of branding and marketing.

Comment: This is true; 'Flappy' is not a real word to my knowledge.